# Maintaining iOS portrait orientation from a static library for one view controller only

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uiviewcontroller

I know similar questions have been asked before, but this is a more specific use case (controlling orientation from a static library, cannot write in root view controller).

I have a static library which adds UI elements as overlays to a passed view controller (the client's root view controller) as subviews. Problem is our UI elements support portrait orientation only, while our client's application may support both portrait and landscape. This is fine, as long as our UI elements don't autorotate when our client's views do.

I'd like to lock the orientation to portrait only for our view controller only. In iOS 6, when I use the following code in my library's view controller, it doesn't affect the behaviour of autorotate at all:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return NO;
}

-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    NSInteger orientationMask = 0;
    if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait])
        orientationMask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    return orientationMask;
}
```

When I put the same code in the root view controller, it works perfectly, with the app no longer auto-rotating. However, this is not an option for us since in production we will not have access to our client's root view controller. Is there a way to either lock view orientation from NOT a root view controller, or lock orientation for a single view controller only? Any other way of achieving what we need that I'm not thinking of? Hoping for solutions that work in iOS <= 6 if at all possible

Comment: How do you account for the device already being in landscape when your elements are instantiated?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't lock orientation only for one view controller in whole application . So you have to set transform angle with parent view frame on view launch and on change of orientation.

You add code for those view controller class

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width)];
    CGFloat radians = atan2f(self.view.transform.b, self.view.transform.a);
    if (radians!=M_PI_2) {
        [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)];

    }

}
```

}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{

  UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
  if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
     [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width)];
      CGFloat radians = atan2f(self.view.transform.b, self.view.transform.a);
      if (radians!=M_PI_2) {
          [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)];

  ```
  }
  ```

  }else{

  [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
      CGFloat radians = atan2f(self.view.transform.b, self.view.transform.a);
      if (radians!=0) {
          [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)];

  ```
  }
  ```

  }
  }